# Unexpected String Behaviour

Tags: c++

If I enter a string Beckham12David it will show error as expected and ask to enter the string again. If I enter *david* then it will show the error but if I enter *beckham* it will accept the string

Code Below:

```
    int i=0;
    char str[15];
    cout<<"\n\n Enter String(Only aplhabets)";
    gets(str);
    a:
    while (str[i])
      {
          if (isalpha(str[i]))
          {
          }
          else
          {
          cout<<"\n\nWrong String Entered!!!! Please Enter again";
          gets(str);
          goto a;
          }
          i++;
       }
       getch();
     }
```

Comment: Enable all warnings & debugging info during compilation (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: sidebar: delete `gets()` from any code you're writing. It is a terrible function that is so bad it has been deprecated and is not long for this world.

Comment: Also, consider using in C++ the `std::string`

Comment: do you need to reset i to 0 after a: ?

Comment: goto is also considered harmful...  use a forever - for(;;) loop and break when the string is correct.

Comment: ...and add `std::getline` to that "should be using" list.

Comment: sidebar #2: read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) and get rid of the goto!

Comment: Thank u so much.....i replaced **while(str[i])** with **for(i=0;str[i];i++)** and it worked...now i know my mistake thank u so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets have a look at the value of `str` while your iterating:

```
str[15] = "Beckham12David";
                  ^
                cursor
```

The `is_alpha` test fails on the character `'1'`. Now you test with `"david"`. `gets` will take the input from `stdin` and save it to your string with a `\0` termination symbol:

```
str[15] = "david*m12David"; // * as \0, sorry :(
                  ^
                cursor
```

Thus the cursor still points to a malicious number! However, when you input `"beckham"`, you end up with:

```
str[15] = "beckham*2David"; // * as \0, sorry :(
                  ^
                cursor
```

Thus `while(str[i])` is false and your program exits. In order to fix this you should set `i` to zero right after your label.

Even better, stick to C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main(){
    std::string str;
    int (*isalpha)(int) = std::isalpha;// necessary as std::isalpha is overloaded
    for(;;){
      std::getline(std::cin, str);      
      if(std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), isalpha)){
        break;
      } else {
        std::cout << "Please enter only letters\n";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: the error is in same session. Like their r 5 alphabets and then a numeric number so when it ask again to enter then i need to enter at least a 5 letter word. Example i entered United1Kingdom...it will ask to enter again....if i enter only kim it will ask again to enter whereas if i enter Mercedes it will not show a error

Comment: Thank u so much.....i replaced "while(str[i])" with for(i=0;str[i];i++) and it worked...now i know my mistake thank u so much :)

Comment: @tut: If you had a look at the other comments, you might knew that you have some more problems than a non-working program. Read a C++ introduction book, because your current code consists of C/C++ and BASIC mentality, which eventually leads to horrible code.

Comment: It was just a part of my main program. I used goto here just to present my Problem more specifically but it just backfired me :(. I will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
 cin >> str;
 cin.ignore(); // if entered more than 15 chars
```

Or try out [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)

Comment: This may be a useful comment, but it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I know... but I dont have enough points for commenting :(. But I thought it might help

Answer (score 0):

does this happen making the different inputs on the same debug session or each input on a different debug session? if it is on different runs..  than it is weird.. do if it is all on the same session.. it might be from the bug you have..
you are not resetting the `i` after you input another string.. the correct code should be

```
int i=0;
char str[15];
cout<<"\n\n Enter String(Only aplhabets)";
gets(str);
a:
while (str[i])
  {
      if (isalpha(str[i]))
      {
      }
      else
      {
      cout<<"\n\nWrong String Entered!!!! Please Enter again";
      gets(str);
      i=0;
      goto a;
      }
      i++;
   }
   getch();
```

notice the `i=0` so you restart analyzing the new string from the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you used white spaces ?
   For example: david_, where _ is space ? isalpha for space return false.
2. Try to avoid jump instruction - goto - in the future.

good luck!

Comment: No i haven't use space.....i corrected my mistake....i need to initialize i=0 every time i accept the string